# FineUploader - Passing customers parameters to the "Signature Endpoint"

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I've been looking around for a bit, and I found that there is no method to allow me to pass custom POST parameters to the signature endpoint.

I'm using this because I'd like to build a generic server-side API, that allows all types of client-side uploaders.  FineUploader is one of them.

In order for the server-side API to recognize the type of client making the call, I would need to know "which uploader" called my API.

I was wondering if there is a way to add custom parameters to for the signature endpoint.

(BTW, I did notice I can pass custom parameters for success and delete endpoints)

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Cheers,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that there is no API method or option to specify your own custom parameters to be sent with the S3 or Azure signature requests.  You can track case [#996](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/996), which will be updated when we begin work on this.

There are a couple other ways you can send information along with the signature request: cookies and query parameters.  The latter is probably the best option.  Simply include query parameters in the URL of the `signature.endpoint` option.  For example:

```
signature: {
    endpoint: '/my/signature/endpoint?foo=bar&abc=123'
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I did for the time being.  I do look forward for the feature soon.  Thanks for the quick response as always Ray!